# Derivative of Left invarinat differential form

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-forms

Let $\omega:G\rightarrow \Lambda^1 T^*G$ be a left invarinat $1$-form on $G$ i.e., $(L_g)^*\omega=\omega$ for each $g\in G$.

Is it true that $\omega(Y):G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is constant for any vector field $Y:G\rightarrow TG$ of $G$?

I see that if $Y$ is of the form $A^*$ for some $A\in \mathfrak{g}$ then $\omega(Y)$ is the constant function $A$.

Given $A\in \mathfrak{g}$, we have $A^*:G\rightarrow TG$ is defined as $A^*(g)=(L_g)_{*,e}(A)$.

We have $\omega(Y):G\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $g\mapsto \omega(g)(Y(g))$.

As $\omega$ is left invariant, we have $\omega(g)(v)=\omega(e)((L_{g^{-1}})_{*,g}(v))$.

For $Y=A^*$, we have $$\omega(g)(Y(g))=\omega(g)(A^*(g))
=\omega(e)((L_{g^{-1}})_{*,g}((L_g)_{*,e}(A)))=\omega(e)(A).$$
Thus, $\omega(Y):G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the constant function $\omega(e)(A)$ when $Y=A^*$.

> Is it true for an arbitrary vector field $Y$ on $G$ that $\omega(Y)$ is constant for a left invariant $1$-form $\omega$ on $G$?

We have $d\omega(X,Y)=\frac{1}{2}(X(\omega(Y))-Y(\omega(X))-\omega[X,Y])$.

As mentioned above, $\omega(A^*)$ is constant, so, $B^*(\omega(A^*))$ is zero map and for similar reason $A^*(\omega(B^*))$ is zero map for any $A,B\in \mathfrak{g}$. So, $d\omega(A^*,B^*)=-\frac{1}{2}\omega[A^*,B^*]$.

In case $\omega(Y)$ is constant for any vector field $Y$ on $G$ we will then have $d\omega(X,Y)=-\frac{1}{2}\omega[X,Y]$.

I do not think this is true but [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurer%E2%80%93Cartan_form#Properties) says it is true for any vector fields $X,Y$ on $G$ not necessarily left invariant vector fields i.e., of the form $A^*,B^*$ for some $A,B\in \mathfrak{g}$.

EDIT : Wikipedia section says the following :

> In particular, if $X$ and $Y$ are left-invariant, then $X(\omega (Y))=Y(\omega (X))=0,$ so $$d\omega (X,Y)+\frac{1}{2}[\omega (X),\omega (Y)]=0$$ 
>    but the left-invariant fields span the tangent space at any point (the push-forward of a basis in $T_eG$ under a diffeomorphism is still a basis), so the equation is true for **any pair of vector fields $X$ and $Y$**. This is known as the Maurer–Cartan equation.

Comment: Notice that $\mathrm{d}\omega(X,Y)$ can be equal to $-\frac{1}{2}[\omega(X),\omega(Y)]$ without $\omega(X)$ and $\omega(Y)$ being constant. Everything that you have written is true and the Wikipedia section you quote is also true. What is used in the Wikipedia article is that $(X,Y)\mapsto\mathrm{d}\omega+\frac{1}{2}[\omega(X),\omega(Y)]$ is $C^\infty$-bilinear, it is a $(2,0)$-tensor.

Comment: It can happen that $\omega(Y)$ and $\omega(X)$ are not constant but $X(\omega(Y))-Y(\omega(X))=0$... I was reading what is written in Wikipedia in a strange way so I got confused..  @C.Falcon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $G=\mathbb{R}$ with coordinate $t$. The 1-form $\omega=\mathrm{d}t$ is left invariant. Now choose any non-constant vector field, e.g. $Y=t\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$. Then $\omega(Y)=t$.

Of course, as you say, evaluating a left-invariant 1-form on a left-invariant vector field does result in a constant function.

EDIT: To conclude the Maurer-Cartan equation just take arbitrary vector fields $X,Y$ and express them as $X=f_iX^i,Y=g_iX^i$ for some left-invariant vector fields $X^i$. Then notice that the equation is (bi)linear over functions so the case of left-invariant vector fields implies the general case.

Comment: 10 seconds before you post your answer. I have edited the question. :) Please have a look at that.... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurer%E2%80%93Cartan_form#Properties

Comment: The article only claims that $\omega(Y)$ is constant when $\omega$ and $Y$ are left-invariant. A few lines later, it gives the general formula for $\mathrm{d}\omega$ when $X,Y$ are arbitrary, but then it returns to the special case that they are left-invariant. So all your calculations are correct and in agreement with the article but the answer to your question is no.

Comment: Thanks for the example.. I agree that answer is no... Wikipedia page says "but the left-invariant fields span the tangent space at any point (the push-forward of a basis in TeG under a diffeomorphism is still a basis), so the equation is true for any pair of vector fields X and Y. This is known as the Maurer–Cartan equation. It is often written as..." see before Maurer-Cartan frame section...

Comment: As $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite dimensional let $\{A_1,\cdots,A_n\}$ be a basis for $\mathfrak{g}$.. Let $Y$ be a vector field on $G$.. Fix $g\in G$.. We have $Y(g)=A^*(g)$ for some $A\in \mathfrak{g}$... So, $Y(g)=(\sum_{i=1}^n a_iA_i)^*(g)$ for some $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$ i.e., $Y(g)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iA_i^*(g)$.. Here, $a_i$ depends on $g$.. Once you vary $g$ over $G$ you get smooth maps $a_i:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.. So, we have $Y=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i A_i^*$ where $a_i:G\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are smooth maps and $A_i^*:G\rightarrow TG$ are left invarinat vect fields..

Comment: This is what you mean when you write $X=f_i X^i$, right? I got the idea... Thank you...

Comment: Yep! Now you just plug that into the equation and see that it linear over functions

Comment: We have $\omega(fY)=f\omega(Y)$... For simplicity, let $X=a_1A_1^*+a_2A_2^*, Y=b_1A_1^*+b_2A_2^*$.. Then, $\omega(Y)=\omega(b_1A_1^*+b_2A_2^*)=b_1\omega(A_1^*)+b_2\omega(A_2^*)$.. We then have $$X(\omega(Y))=X(b_1\omega(A_1^*)+b_2\omega(A_2^*))=\sum _{i, j}a_i b_jA_i^*\omega(A_j^*)=0$$ similarly $Y(\omega(X))=0$.. Which then imply that $d\omega(X,Y)=-\frac{1}{2}\omega([X,Y])$